# Unable set handler URL of C#

Tags: c#, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, flowplayer

Currently i'm working on flowplayer with nimble streaming , i'm returning Url from handler.
By setting up src to handler is successfully redirect to handler but flowplayer is not able to setting up return output of handler(i.e. handler is returning m3u8 URL)..below is the example code

```
<div>
    <input type="button" id="Test" value="click" />
</div><br />
<div>
    <input type="button" id="Test2" value="click2" />
</div><br />
```

```
<script>
$(function () {
    var api = flowplayer("#player", {
        splash: true,
        embed: { skin: "//releases.flowplayer.org/7.0.2/skin/skin.css" },
        ratio: 9 / 16,
        seekable: true,
        clip: {
            live: false,
            autoplay: false, 
            sources: [
              {
                  type: "application/x-mpegurl",
                  src: "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8081/videos/fast.mp4/playlist.m3u8"
              }
            ]
        },
        onload: function () {
            alert("player loaded.");
        },

    })
    $("#Test").click(function () {
        flowplayer().load("http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8086/vod/edge/camera2/profile16/camera2_profile16_2017-03-02_055323.mp4/playlist.m3u8");
    })

    $("#Test2").click(function () {
        flowplayer().load("http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8081/ProxyDemo/ReverseProxy.ashx");
    })
})
</script>
```

Comment: Does the handler return a string with the URL or does it redirect to the URL?

Comment: Sorry boss but issue is resolved and You answered late ;)